# Why the swap member function do not need to use pointer?

Tags: go, heap, priority-queue

I am new to Golang. When I try to implement my first PriorityQueue, I find that the Push and Pop function needs to use the pointer of the member but the Swap does not.

I know that if you use the pointer in the member function, it means you can change the instance itself instead of its copy. But why does the Swap can use the copy instead of the pointer?

```
type maxHeap []int

func (max maxHeap) Len() int {
    return len(max)
}

func (max maxHeap) Less(a, b int) bool {
    return max[a] > max[b]
}

func (max maxHeap) Swap(a, b int) {
    max[a], max[b] = max[b], max[a]
}

func (max *maxHeap) Push(a interface{}) {
    *max = append(*max, a.(int))
}
func (max *maxHeap) Pop() interface{} {
    x := (*max)[len(*max)-1]
    *max = (*max)[0 : len(*max)-1]
    return x
}
```

Comment: Modifying the value of a slice _element_ doesn’t modify the slice itself at all. Slices in Go are not extensive but mere views into a backing array.

Answer (score 2):

Try this as an exercise: write *all* the functions using a pointer receiver.  In each function, grab the current value of the pointer at the top, to use until you need to *change* the value stored through the pointer.

So `Swap` and `Push`, respectively, become:

```golang
func (p *maxHeap) Swap(a, b int) {
    max := *p
    max[a], max[b] = max[b], max[a]
}
func (p *maxHeap) Push(a interface{}) {
    max := *p
    *p = append(max, a.(int))
}
```

Repeat for the other functions as needed.

Now, go back through each converted function.  *Which ones assign a new value to `*p`?  Which functions never assign a **new** value and just keep using `max`?*

When you answer this question, you should find yourself enlightened.

Side note: since `Push` immediately converts `a` to `int`, it probably should just take `int`.  Likewise, `Pop` should just return `int`.  Alternatively, well, see [the standard `container/heap` package](https://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/).

Answer (score 0):

The reason lies in the fact that a slice, in your case `[]int`, really is a pointer. A slice consists of a pointer to the underlying memory, the current length and total capacity of that memory. That means a slice is really a data structure with these three things:

1. memory pointer
2. length
3. capacity

You can think of it as a

```
type slice struct {
    data     unsafe.Pointer
    length   int
    capacity int
}
```

Now when you call `append` it takes a slice as input and returns a slice as output.

In case the input slice has enough capacity to add the new elements, it is changed in place (append is a special built-in function, it does not need a slice **pointer** as input, it changes the slice anyway).

In case the input slice does not have the capcity to add the new items, a new slice is created with enough capacity, the old slice is copied into it and then the new data is added at the end. This new slice is then returned.

In your case you want to change your heap in the `Push` function. The `append` function might return a new slice and you have to overwrite your existing slice with it. That means you need the pointer to the slice as you want to replace the slice structure.

In the `Swap` and `Less` functions, you change the contents of the slice, not the slice data structure itself. You can access the data in the slice with the memory pointer that the slice contains. This means these functions use a copy of the slice data structure but both the original and the copy of the slice data structure point to the same underlying memory. The memory referenced by the slices is the same. Since you do not call append here the slice itself does not need to be updated.

In the `Pop` function you again change the slice data structure because you change its length field. That is why you need a pointer to the slice here.